# Is the infimum of a measures of balls of varying radii a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the following function: $$m(t) = \inf\limits_{x \in {supp} \, \mu} \mu(B(x,t)), $$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure with compact support.

I am attempting to show that this function is left-continuous (or even continuous, but left-continuous suffices).

**My Attempt:** \begin{align} \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mu(B(x,t-\dfrac{1}{n})) &= \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\int_{B(x,t-\frac{1}{n})} d\mu \\
&=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \int_{supp \,\mu} \chi_{B(x,t-\frac{1}{n})} d\mu \\
&= \int_{supp \,\mu} \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \chi_{B(x,t-\frac{1}{n})} d\mu \\
&= \mu(B(x,t))
\end{align}

where I used the Dominated Convergence Theorem as $\chi_{B(x,t-\frac{1}{n})} \leq 1$ and the function identically equal to $1$ is integrable in $supp \, \mu$ as this set is compact.

Taking infimum over $x \in supp \, \mu$ we get $$ \inf\limits_{x\in supp \, \mu}  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mu(B(x,t-\dfrac{1}{n})) = \inf\limits_{supp \, \mu}\mu(B(x,t)) = m(t).$$

**My doubts:**

1. Is my use of the DCT justified?
2. If I can swap the limite and the infimum on the LHS I am done, but I am not sure exactly if I can do that.